# PHP multiple class Inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance

I have a situation where I have three classes:

```
<?php 
class A {
    protected a_val = 'some_val';
    public function read_a_val( return $this->a_val; );
}

class B extends A {
    protected b_val = 'some_val_2';
    public function read_b_val( return $this->b_val; );
}

class C extends B {
    protected c_val = 'some_val_3';
    public function read_c_val( return $this->c_val; );
    public function c_read_a_val( return $this->a_val; );
}

$obj = new C;
$val = $obj->read_a_val();   // <-- throws error; undefined method
$val = $obj->a_val;          // <-- throws error; cannot access protected property
$val = $obj->c_read_a_val();  // works.
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?  PHP supports multi-level inheritance... what am I missing?   It seems like inside of C can access the parent(s), no problem, but the variable $obj can't.  Should $obj be able to access the inherited content of A (protected as well)? Note: using PHP v5.6.25

Comment: `$obj->read_a_val()` shouldn't (and doesn't) throw any errors.

Comment: Editing the question to match the answer you've been given makes it useless to anybody else

Comment: I actually corrected the question BEFORE he posted his reply because I saw I had typed it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?php 
class A {
    protected $a_val = 'some_val';
    function read_a_val(){ return $this->a_val; }
}

class B extends A {
    protected $b_val = 'some_val_2';
function read_b_val(){ return $this->b_val; }
}

class C extends B {
    protected $c_val = 'some_val_3';
function read_c_val(){ return $this->c_val; }
    function c_read_a_val(){ return $this->a_val; }
}

$obj = new C;
$val1 = $obj->read_a_val();
$val2 = $obj->c_read_a_val(); 

var_dump($val1, $val2);
```

The syntax you used to write your code was utterly wrong. The correct way to define a method is as follows:

```
function read_a_val(){ return $this->a_val; }
```

Not:

```
//See the curly braces in the above code and none here.
public function read_a_val( return $this->a_val; );
```

Similarly all variables in php should start with `$` like `$a_val` not `a_val`. And `protected` properties are not available outside the class and its child classes.

Have a look at these pages: [Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php), [A simple tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php), and [OOP Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I corrected as soon as I looked at what I had posted, but the question remains, why couldn't $obj access the protected content from A?  According to the PHP manual, it implements normal inheritance, so all sub-classes that inherit from A (even through B) should have access to protected content from A.

Comment: Ahh, ok.  Got it.  I was confused on the way it handles 'protected'.  Thanks mega6382.